# Using MySQL to create a DB and populate it with SQLAlchemy and Pandas

Tags: mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I made a Table Schema using MySQl Work Bench and want to populate it with tweets i **scraped**. All Foreign Keys and Primary Keys are set so far.
But i can´t get SQLalchemy to use the schema and populate it.
I tried it with this command line:  `user_df.to_sql(name='user', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False)`
I shortend the code of the table creation to match only the "user" section.
The Error, which i get is
`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'")`

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema CapitolRiot
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema CapitolRiot
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `CapitolRiot` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `CapitolRiot` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CapitolRiot`.`User`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CapitolRiot`.`User` (
  `userName` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `displayName` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `description` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `friendsCount` INT NULL,
  `createdAt` DATE NULL,
  `followersCount` INT NULL,
  `statusesCount` INT NULL,
  `favouritesCount` INT NULL,
  `listedCount` INT NULL,
  `mediaCount` INT NULL,
  `location` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `protected` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `linkUrl` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `linkTcourl` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `profileImageUrl` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `profileBannerUrl` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `url` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `verified` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `userID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `userID_UNIQUE` ON `CapitolRiot`.`User` (`userID` ASC) VISIBLE;
```

Comment: Might be helpful to post the error output of `user_df.to_sql(name='user', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False)`, will make it likelier that someone out there can spot the issue.

Comment: I edited the question to contain what you asked for

Comment: nice, ty that's extremely helpful

Comment: Though I still don't entirely understand what was run and how it resulted in that error log. Is `user_df.to_sql(name='user', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False)` running the attached sql statement, or is it doing something else?

Comment: I tried to write that to the table `user_df = pandas.json_normalize(user)`

Comment: What's that `user` object look like? Could it be it's not converting nicely to a row in that `CapitolRiot` table schema.

Comment: In particular, am curious to know from `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'")`if your `user` object has a field called `id`

Comment: User looks like a regular json `{'username': 'EricFlut', 'displayname': 'Eric', 'id': 350130565, 'description': '', 'rawDescription': '', 'descriptionUrls': None, 'verified': False, 'created': '2011-08-07T07:38:54+00:00', 'followersCount': 149, 'friendsCount': 452, 'statusesCount': 756, 'favouritesCount': 141, 'listedCount': 7, 'mediaCount': 31, 'location': '', 'protected': False, 'linkUrl': None, 'linkTcourl': None, 'profileImageUrl': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1347294339672715267/HGJ4s-sv_normal.jpg', 'profileBannerUrl': None, 'url': 'https://twitter.com/EricFlut'}`

Comment: Found it...SQLAlchemy demanded columns i hadn´t created or slightly misnamed in MySQL. After fixing that, it worked

Comment: yeah I was picturing `id` -> `userID` lol.

Answer (score 0):

So piecing it together, you're running:

```
user_df = pandas.json_normalize(user)
```

which is failing with:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'")
```

given that your user struct looks like:

```
{'username': 'EricFlut', 'displayname': 'Eric', 'id': 350130565, 'description': '', 'rawDescription': '', 'descriptionUrls': None, 'verified': False, 'created': '2011-08-07T07:38:54+00:00', 'followersCount': 149, 'friendsCount': 452, 'statusesCount': 756, 'favouritesCount': 141, 'listedCount': 7, 'mediaCount': 31, 'location': '', 'protected': False, 'linkUrl': None, 'linkTcourl': None, 'profileImageUrl': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1347294339672715267/HGJ4s-sv_normal.jpg', 'profileBannerUrl': None, 'url': 'https://twitter.com/EricFlut'}
```

And your table struct like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CapitolRiot`.`User` (
  `userName` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `displayName` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `description` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `friendsCount` INT NULL,
  `createdAt` DATE NULL,
  `followersCount` INT NULL,
  `statusesCount` INT NULL,
  `favouritesCount` INT NULL,
  `listedCount` INT NULL,
  `mediaCount` INT NULL,
  `location` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `protected` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `linkUrl` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `linkTcourl` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `profileImageUrl` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `profileBannerUrl` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `url` LONGTEXT NULL,
  `verified` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `userID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`))
```

I think that `pymysql.err.OperationalError` is originally getting thrown by mysql, python's just reporting it back to you. My guess is that mysql didn't know where to write the `user.id` field you provided - maybe because sqlalchemy didn't do its mapping correctly.

I know it's a compact document with a lot of content, but https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping is probably the best place to look.